# Binding collection of complex objects in MVC 6 model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, model-binding

**Greetings everyone**!
I am binding complex object *FullAddress* while POSTing data to a Controller.
**VIEW**:

```
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Address</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <textarea asp-for="FullAddress.AddressLine" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="FullAddress.AddressLine" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="row col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" >
                    <input asp-for="FullAddress.IsPrimary" checked="checked" type="radio" value="true" class="col-md-1" style="width:5px;" />
                    <span class="col-md-4">primary</span>
                    <input type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-md-1" style="width:9px;" onclick="addAddressTxtField()">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="addresses-to-add"></div>
        </fieldset>
```

**MODEL**:

```
    public class CreatePersonViewModel
{

    public AddressVm FullAddress { get; set; }

}

public class AddressVm {
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

So far so good, everyone's happy. But then, all of the sudden, I append similar chunk of html code into my div using Javascript. 
**JS:**

```
function addAddressTxtField() {
var html = '<div class="form-group" style="display:none"><div class="col-md-7">'
+ '<textarea class="form-control" name=FullAddress.AddressLine"></textarea>'
+ '<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="FullAddress.AddressLine"></span>'
+'</div><div class="row col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">'
+ '<input class="col-md-1" type="radio" name="FullAddress.IsPrimary" data-val-required="The IsPrimary field is required." data-val="true" style="width:5px;" value="true">'
+'<span class="col-md-4">primary</span>'
+ '<input class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-md-1" type="button" style="width:9px;" value="-" onclick="removeTextfield(this)"></div></div>' 

var newAddressTxtfield = $('#addresses-to-add').append(html);
newAddressTxtfield.children().show('slow'); };
```

That is resulting having two textareas for the user inputs and two radio buttons. Right? Therefore I am forced to use a collection of my AddressVm models. Something like **this**:

```
public IList<AddressVm> AddressList { get; set; }
```

So this doesn't really fit to my code, because I can't use a for loop to assign the fields. Of course, I can do the ugly stuff - hardcode the brackets and indexes.
Like this:

```
<textarea asp-for="AddressList[0].AddressLine" class="form-control"></textarea>
<span asp-validation-for="AddressList[0].AddressLine" class="text-danger" />
```

And later create js variable that will iterate each time the user adds a new input field, **but that is not really what I am looking for**. Ideally, I would like to use IEnumerable or anything that is equally "clean". What would be the best solution to my problem, that you recommend? Maybe I should use **IDictionary** or create a **custom model binding**? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use a Dictionary of a custom ModelBinder. You must use indexers for you collection properties. Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Comment: Right, okay. I see that @StephenMuecke has already answered to my problem twice in other posts. I was looking for that for half a day =). Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The described approach work for me very well. So now I can move on. If you want to reply to this post too I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks